# How can I get vim to stop putting comments in front of new lines?

Tags: formatting, comments

I'm editing my `.vimrc` file, and I am including comments. When I have a comment like this:

```
" example comment
```

And then hit enter at the end of the line after finishing the comment, the next line is automatically set up as a comment (the quotes are automatically inserted):

```
" example comment
"
```

How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This is controlled with the `formatoptions` setting; from [`:help fo-table`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table):

> You can use the `'formatoptions'` option  to influence how Vim formats text.
>       `'formatoptions'` is a string that can contain any of the letters below.  The
>       default setting is `tcq`.  You can separate the option letters with commas for
>       readability.

Note that the statement about the "defaults" is somewhat misleading, since many filetypes change the formatoptions to best suit the file type; for example in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/vim.vim`:

```
" Set 'formatoptions' to break comment lines but not other lines,
" and insert the comment leader when hitting <CR> or using "o".
setlocal fo-=t fo+=croql
```

You can view the current `formatoptions` with:

```
:set fo?
  formatoptions=jcroql
```

And see where they were set like so:

```
:verbose set fo?
  formatoptions=jcroql
      Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/vim.vim
```

In this case, you want to remove the `r` flag, but perhaps also the `c` and `o` flags:

```
r       Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting
        <Enter> in Insert mode.
c       Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting the current comment
        leader automatically.
o       Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or
        'O' in Normal mode.
```

This can be done like so:

```
:set formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=o
```

Note that using `:set formatoptions-=cro` won't work as expected (since it's a string, it will look for the string `cro`, in that order, which often won't work.).

To set the changes *only* for the current buffer, use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`. If you want to *always* have these options, it's probably best to use an `autocmd` in your vimrc; for example:

```
au FileType vim setlocal fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o
```

This will set the options *only* for the 'vim' filetype, and won't interfere with other filetypes.

If you want to *always* set it, use:

```
au FileType * set fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o
```

Just using `set fo-=cro` won't work since many filetypes set/expand `formatoption` (like shown above); the FileType autocmd is executed *after* the filetype files have loaded.

Comment: Confirmed. Also, it's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030639/vim-formatoptions-or

Comment: Adding `au FileType * set fo-=o` to my .vimrc didn't work. I press `o` in a commented line and it still comments it too.

Comment: This has been bugging me for a long time. Default `formatoptions` were wrapping my txt file. I was breaking my head around `textwidth` and `wrapmargin` but nothing worked. Even downgraded my vim from 8.1 to 8.0 thinking that it's a bug. This solved my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your vimrc:

```
au BufEnter * set fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o
```

Using `FileType` won't work since other plugins set `formatoption`.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution for me even when I disable all plugins in Vundle. Using neovim. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @andrewgazelka It's probably set by an ftplugin that's part of your standard Vim installation (i.e. not something you've added via Vundle). Use `:verbose set fo?` to see where the option was set.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very similar to Martin Tournoij (full credit to him).
This just makes it in a single-line command. When you run this, it will disable continuation of comment permanently:

```
echo 'au FileType * set fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o' >> ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: Adding line `au FileType * set fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o` into `.vimrc` is working. I was planning to create a vim-build of my own without this unnecessary crap. Having this setting saves a lot of time!