# set formatoptions in vimrc is being ignored

Tags: vimrc, formatting

Vim automatically continues a comment when I press Enter in Insert mode, which I find helpful.

However, I do not want the comment continued after pressing 'o' from normal mode to insert a new line below the end of the comment.

I read that I need to remove the option `o` from my `formatoptions`, so I put this line right at the end of my vimrc file:

```
set formatoptions-=o
```

But it has changed nothing, and when I execute `:set formatoptions` from iside of vim it shows me my formatoptions are `croql`.

How do I get rid of the 'o'?

### Edit:

I've followed some steps pointed out in the comments by Sato Katsura:

> The solution starts with running `:verb set fo` to see where formatoptions was last modified.

Here's the output to `verb set fo`:

```
  formatoptions=croql
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/vim.vim
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get vim to stop putting comments in front of new lines?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/how-can-i-get-vim-to-stop-putting-comments-in-front-of-new-lines)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem That doesn't solve my problem. As you can see, I have taken the approaches recommended by the answers for that question, and vim's behaviour has not changed.

Comment: Yes, I see that. I was too hasty with my close vote, so I have retracted now. However, now it sounds like a problem with your `.vimrc`, so we can't help at all until you post it. I'm guessing a plugin changes it, or it isn't being source correctly.

Comment: Basically, the question is "why doesn't the line `set formatoptions-=o` in my vimrc work?", that this disables comments when pressing `o` is coincidental :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yeah pretty much... does it need editing?

Comment: Some plugins that you use changed this option, to my suggest you that put `set formatoptions-=o` this line after the plugin installation in your `vimrc`

Comment: @Voldikss I did that :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I can provide a makeshift solution using an autocommand.

The following line in your `.vimrc` file should apply the new formatoptions everywhere:

```
autocmd FileType * set formatoptions-=o
```

However, this doesn't really get to solving the problem; I still don't understand why a simple `set` wasn't enough, and as has been pointed out in the comments this solution is not ideal.

Comment: This may *work*, but it's very [kludgy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge) and not the solution I would recommend.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem hmm, what possible problems could I run into by using this solution? Please feel free to post an answer providing a better solution, I'd obviously prefer it :)

Comment: Why not @DJMcMayhem? The problem is almost certainly because one of the filetypes sets `formatoptions` (e.g. Perl, Ruby, and several others set this). This seems like an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I suppose that's fair. I hadn't thought of that. It just seems strange to change a setting in an autocmd, rather than just setting it directly.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker if you want to propose a reason for this strange behaviour as an answer, feel free! I'm still not sure why I've had to solve it by using an autocmd

Comment: Note that the top answer on the other question actually mentions this: `Note that the statement about the "defaults" is somewhat misleading, since many filetypes change the formatoptions to best suit the file type [..] it's probably best to use an autocmd in your vimrc;` ... I'm not going to mod-hammer it as a dupe because it's my own answer (I'll let the community handle it) , but IMHO @DJMcMayhem was right and it's probably a duplicate after all ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yeah I already noticed this: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/stop-comments-continuing-when-pressing-o/9367?noredirect=1#comment-16308 I'm wondering whether I should report this question as a duplicate, even though the question itself is slightly different to that other one.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The solution should be to solve the problem, rather than getting a bigger hammer. :) In this case, the solution starts with running `:verb set fo` to see where `formatoptions` was last modified.  If it was modified from a `ftplugin`, then it can be overridden in an `after/ftplugin`.  A catch-all `autocmd` just accumulates running the same `set` over and over, and it makes it impossible to have the `o` option when it's actually wanted.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I've done that and now added the output to my question; feel free to analyse!

Comment: Like I said: add `set formatoptions-=o` to a file `after/ftplugin/vim.vim`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Depends on what you want, I guess. Some people might prefer never adding a comment character when using `o` regardless of the filetype, in which case this seems appropriate.

Comment: In my opinion, any plugin that modifies this type of vim behavior should have a bug reported against it. There's no reason for `ftplugin/vim.vim` to do that by default. Given that, this solution has a thumbs up from me, except that I would limit it to the `vim` filetype (instead of using `*`).

Comment: This works for some systems but not on all systems. In my case, it does not work for Linux and Mac. Even if you have used the autocmd in configuration, the `o` option is still set by the ftplugin `vim.vim`.

Comment: @jdhao I am on mac and it's been working for me

Comment: @theonlygusti I am using Neovim. Are your using Vim or Neovim?

Comment: @jdhao I was using vim when I wrote this question. I switched to Neovim recently and it works in Neovim, at least nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

When `vim` starts, it runs `$VIMRUNTIME/ftdetect.vim` to find out what type of file you're editing; then, if you have `'ftplugin'` set, it sources `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim` which sources `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/&filetype.vim` (see `:help startup` for more detail).

You can alter or override `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim` or `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/&filetype.vim`. Create a folder and subfolder in your home directory called `.vim/after`.

If you want to override formatoptions for all filetype plugins, edit `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin.vim`, otherwise edit `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/lua.vim` (or replace `lua` with whichever language - in your case it's `vim`). For a proper explanation of how this works, see `:help 'runtimepath'` (and `:help :runtime`).

Put the following content in the file:

```
set formatoptions-=o
```

You can see whether it's worked by running `:scriptnames`. You should get a list like the following:

```
  1: H:\script\vim\vimrc
  2: H:\script\vim\syntax\syntax.vim
  3: H:\script\vim\syntax\synload.vim
  4: H:\script\vim\syntax\syncolor.vim
  5: H:\script\vim\filetype.vim
  6: ~\vimfiles\ftdetect\log.vim
  7: ~\vimfiles\ftdetect\rdp.vim
  8: ~\vimfiles\ftdetect\scratch.vim
  9: ~\vimfiles\ftdetect\sqlite.vim
 10: ~\vimfiles\ftdetect\todo.vim
 11: H:\script\vim\ftplugin.vim
 12: ~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin.vim
 13: ~\vimfiles\colors\desert.vim
 14: H:\script\vim\defaults.vim
 15: H:\script\vim\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
 16: H:\script\vim\plugin\gzip.vim
 17: H:\script\vim\plugin\logiPat.vim
 18: H:\script\vim\plugin\manpager.vim
 19: H:\script\vim\plugin\matchparen.vim
 20: H:\script\vim\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
 21: H:\script\vim\plugin\rrhelper.vim
 22: H:\script\vim\plugin\spellfile.vim
 23: H:\script\vim\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
 24: H:\script\vim\plugin\tohtml.vim
 25: H:\script\vim\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
 26: H:\script\vim\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
 27: H:\script\vim\syntax\lua.vim
 28: H:\script\vim\ftplugin\lua.vim
```

Note lines 11 and 12. Your file paths will look a bit different.

Comment: This might be helpful for someone. In my situation, I use vim-plug, and some plugins(I don't know which) changed the `formatoptions`, however my `.vim/after` is sourced after those plugins...

Comment: I think the correct command is `:scriptnames`.

Comment: By trial and error, I learned that trying to force `formatoptions` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugins.vim` does not work -- then I encountered [this argument](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20227/7649) which sort-of explains why.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar experience as OP.

I found that `t` was being added to my `formatoptions` despite deliberately attempting to disable it.

After using `:verbose set fo` to be certain it was coming from .vimrc, I noticed that the behavior seemed to be dependent on where I put the formatoptions in my .vimrc file. I discovered that it was happening because of where I had placed `set nocompatible` in my file:

```
set formatoptions=qj
set nocompatible

:set fo?
  formatoptions=tcq
```

It turns out that this is specifically called out in `:help nocompatible`:

```
                   'compatible' 'cp' 'nocompatible' 'nocp'
'compatible' 'cp'   boolean (default on, off when a |vimrc| or |gvimrc|
                    file is found, reset in |defaults.vim|)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    This option has the effect of making Vim either more Vi-compatible, or
    make Vim behave in a more useful way.

    This is a special kind of option, because when it's set or reset,
    other options are also changed as a side effect.
    NOTE: Setting or resetting this option can have a lot of unexpected
    effects: Mappings are interpreted in another way, undo behaves
    differently, etc.  If you set this option in your vimrc file, you
    should probably put it at the very start.
```

After following this good advice, my `formatoptions` were preserved as desired.  I don't know if OP was running into this exact problem or if it was some other interaction, but I was happy to find out what was causing it.  Hopefully this helps someone else figure out what's (initially inexplicably) changing their settings.

I also like theonlygusti's autocmd- there are some options I just never want set no matter the file type. I'm looking at you, `t`.

Answer (score 2):

Since lot of us Vim users are suffering from this, I went and investigated this bit more.

My solution is to create the `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin.vim` as suggested by @abcq2 just to realize, it won't change anything. Given the list given by `:scriptnames`, that file is source way too early. However, the second suggestion of creating a `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/lua.vim` for LUA-files does help.

By `strace`ing, I learned that file-type generic after-plugins are sourced before the file-type and file-type specific after-plugins are sourced after the file-type. Not very intuitive, but that's how it works.

There is more information in [my blog](https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/442-Vims-comment-line-leaking-fix!-Part-3.html) about this.

Comment: I am not sure why you think an `after/ftplugin` would help. Rather the better way is to use filetype specific overrides (using either a FileType autocommand or a specific `after/<filetype>.vim` file). See also the help at `:h ftplugin-overrule`

Comment: I'm thinking it would help, because @abcq2 suggested it in his answer above. I think I am using `after/<filetype>.vim` in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I looked to see which files/paths that `vim` attempted to load, using `strace` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495323/550454)), then created a `~/.vim/after/plugin/` directory (it was the last config location that `vim` attempted to load), then symlinked my `~/.vimrc` into that location:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/after/plugin/
ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.vim/after/plugin/
```

#### What I did with `strace`:

Basically, I ran:

```
strace -o ~/vim_strace vim
```

...then immediately quit `vim` (`:q!`). Next, I loaded up `~/vim_strace` (`$ vim ~/vim_strace`) and went to the end (`:$`). Then I started reading from the bottom looking for lines beginning with `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/karl/.....`.

The first thing I see is:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/karl/.viminfo", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

But that isn't where I want my config options. The next line, right above the `.viminfo` line, was:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/karl/.vim/after/plugin/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

..."No such file or directory", eh? Seems like a winner. So, that's the one I chose.

Now, works perfectly.

Hope this help someone somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see how this is an answer to this question. Can you please clarify and explain why this will solve the problem with formatoptions?

Comment: Because it actually gets `vim` to honor the options in the `.vimrc` file. Please re-read, and make sure that you understand, both the question and the my answer.

Comment: 1) Your (whole) vimrc is not really supposed to run on the context of a plugin. 2) Something like adding a one-line `~/.vim/after/plugin/formatoptions.vim` with `set fo-=o` is more palatable... But that still **doesn't work** when a filetype plug-in overrides that. For example, open Vim (with no file, or an unrelated file), then use `:e` to open or create a `*.vim` file. You'll see that formatoptions has `o` in it again, since that's being set for that buffer by `ftplugin/vim.vim` and your `after/plugin` file won't be able to override it.

Comment: In any case... Your answer is not totally clear on what you're trying to accomplish here. I can see (now?) that **you're trying to load vimrc last in the startup process, after all plug-ins.** Your answer doesn't really state that, it would help if you started by explaining that... Also, while strace is nice and all, answering "which directory is last" is pretty easy, just looking at `:set rtp?` you'll see that `~/.vim/after` is last. But, as mentioned before, this doesn't really work since `fo` will be reset by ft plugins and that's really the issue here.

Comment: It absolutely does, and it absolutely works. I was having the *exact* same problem as the OP after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. My solution "fixed" it, in that it loaded my `~/.vimrc` *after* the other plugins were loaded, thus allowing my `~/.vimrc` to override the defaults, as intended.