# How can I insert text from a function without triggering autoinsertion of comments?

Tags: vimscript

I have this in my `.vimrc`

```
function HeaderTpl(fchar, boxchar, width)
    let sfile = expand("%:p")
    return a:fchar . " " . repeat(a:boxchar, a:width) . "\n"
            \ . a:fchar . " " . sfile . "\n"
            \ . a:fchar . "\n"
            \ . a:fchar . " " . strftime("%FT%T %z") . "\n"
            \ . a:fchar . " " . repeat(a:boxchar, a:width) . "\n"
endfunction

imap <silent>  ###  <C-R>=HeaderTpl('#', '-', 71)<CR>
imap <silent>  ///  <C-R>=HeaderTpl('//', '-', 70)<CR>
```

This works almost perfectly as if I type `###` in blank file I get this header

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# /path/to/current/file.conf
#
# 2017-01-03T20:02:50 +0100
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but if the file type is defined (something like `vim python_script.py`) then I get something like this:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# # /path/to/current/file.conf
# #
# # 2017-01-03T20:02:50 +0100
# # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
```

I think that additional `#` is caused by the `autoindent` or `smartindent`.

My question: how do I prevent this additional `#` to be inserted? One of my ideas was to temporary switch off `autoindent` and `smartindent` but how to do it?

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
```

Comment: `<C-R>=` inserts as if typed. Try `:put =...`. Example at `:h :put`.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the `r` flag in `formatoptions`. See [How can I get vim to stop putting comments in front of new lines?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/1983/51).

One way to fix it is to:

- Check if `r` is in `formatoptions` (with `stridx(&formatoptions, 'r')`
- Remove it from `formatoptions` if it is with `set formatoptions-=r` and storing a local variable to track if it was set.
- Add it back with `set formatoptions+=r` at the end if it was set.

As mentioned in the comments, you can also use the `paste` option to avoid some other side-effects that may occur.

However, this method won't work very well with your insert mode mapping, since that relies on the return value of the function. It *can* be done, but a better way is probably to use `setline()`:

```
function! HeaderTpl(fchar, boxchar, width)
    let sfile = expand("%:p")
    call setline('.', [a:fchar . " " . repeat(a:boxchar, a:width),
        \ a:fchar . " " . sfile,
        \ a:fchar,
        \ a:fchar . " " . strftime("%FT%T %z"),
        \ a:fchar . " " . repeat(a:boxchar, a:width)
    \ ])

    return ''
endfunction

inoremap <silent> ### <C-R>=HeaderTpl('#', '-', 71)<CR>
inoremap <silent> /// <C-R>=HeaderTpl('//', '-', 70)<CR>
```

`setline()` will set the line in the first argument to the text in the second argument. `.` refers to the current line. You can set multiple lines by passing a list (using `\n` won't work).

Comment: Well `setline` is not good too as it overwrites lines below current line. My header is 5 lines so 4 line below current one are overwritten.